# Migrating old website to a new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

### Requirement

Old Domain: abc.com

New Domain: def.com

I wanted my requests from **abc.com/loadsite.action?site=eu** to be redirected to **def.com/eu** but at the same time, I want to make sure if something goes wrong with the new domain, users are still able to use old domain by some means (maybe by adding /old in the URL, abc.com/old/loadsite.com?site=eu).

Currently my vhost configuration looks like below. It redirects to def.com for selected marketplaces but there is no fallback configuration.

```
Listen 12567 NameVirtualHost *:12567
ServerName abc.com ProxyPreserveHost On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(eu) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(in) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(jp) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?loadsite$ http://def.com/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

How can I redirect **abc.com/old/loadsite.action?site=eu** to **abc.com/loadsite.action?site=eu** without getting into cycle?

Any leads here is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/old/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(eu) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(in) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(jp) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?loadsite$ http://def.com/%1? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^/?old/(.*) /$1 [L,NC]
```

The last directive will simply (internally) rewrite `abc.com/old/loadsite.action?site=eu` to `abc.com/loadsite.action?site=eu`. Since %{THE_REQUEST} contains full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server, even after this internal rewrite we can still use this variable to prevent rewrite to new site.

So, `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/old/` adds one more condition: if the original request was beginning with `/old/`, do not rewrite to new site.

Comment: Thanks Dusan, can you help me to understand this? What does RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/old/ mean?

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /old/loadsite.action was not found on this server.

I am getting the above error when I open "abc.com/old/loadsite.action?site=eu"


What does this $1 contains?

Comment: Not sure what is wrong happening here it didn't work.

Comment: `$1` should contain everything that was after `/old/`. Is there a `/loadsite.action` on old server? (if you disable all rewrites, does that work on old server?)

Comment: Yes /loadsite.action works. Since I am selectively migrating marketplaces (eu,in,jp at the moment is migrated) I am still able to load abc.com/loadsite.action?site=us on old server.

Comment: add `LogLevel rewrite:trace6` to your apache configuration, restart, and examine error_log, it should show you exactly what is happening with rewrites

Comment: Can you please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48496190/conditional-or-operation-in-rewriterule as well. Thanks in advance.