# Conditional "OR" operation in RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I want to redirect certain urls of my old website to the new website. This redirection to new website is conditional i.e if query param contains key "site" with value as "eu", "jp" or "in" then only redirect otherwise do not.

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(eu) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(in) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(jp) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^/?fetchHomePage.action$ https://example.com/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^/?fetchFirstPage.action$ https://example.com/firstpage/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^/?fetchSecondPage.action$ https://example.com/fetchsecondpage/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^/?fetchThirdPage.action$ https://example.com/fetchThirdPage/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

With above configuration it works well for path "/fetchHomePage" but for other paths in the URLs ("/fetchFirstPage", "/fetchSecondPage" and "/fetchThirdPage") browser is always redirecting to the new website irrespective of what the site param is there in the query parameter.

Comment: You will need to add the conditions again before each RewriteRule.

Comment: Ya it looks like that is the only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may follow one of these method :

Here you need to add the condition for all the rules.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(eu|in|jp)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?fetchHomePage.action$ https://example.com/%1? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(eu|in|jp)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?fetchFirstPage.action$ https://example.com/firstpage/%1? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(eu|in|jp)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?fetchSecondPage.action$ https://example.com/fetchsecondpage/%1? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(eu|in|jp)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?fetchThirdPage.action$ https://example.com/fetchThirdPage/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

**OR**

You can also write multiple rules but for that you need to remove the    `L` flag from all the rules except last rule.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(eu|in|jp)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?fetchHomePage.action$ https://example.com/%1? [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?fetchFirstPage.action$ https://example.com/firstpage/%1? [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?fetchSecondPage.action$ https://example.com/fetchsecondpage/%1? [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?fetchThirdPage.action$ https://example.com/fetchThirdPage/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

---

L = Last

> *The `[L]` flag causes [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.*

Reference : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Wouldn't in your second suggestion only the first RewriteRule be affected by RewriteCond?

Comment: Also, `[eu|in|jp]` is one character amongst 'e', 'u', '|', 'i', 'n', 'j' et 'p'. For the string "en" or "in" or "jp", it's: `(?:^|&)site=(eu|in|jp)(?:&|$)`.

Comment: @julp thanks for the correction, I've updated answer.

Comment: @DusanBajic I think it should apply the `RewriteCond` for all the below `RewriteRule`

Comment: L means that "if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed", but I don't understand why a rule for "/fetchHomePage.action" will match for URL containing "/fetchFirstPage.action".

Comment: @Lokesh I've tested both above code and is working, you need to use incognito mode of browser. It may be cache issue of 301.

Comment: Can someone help me with the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584765/conditions-in-apache-rewrite-rules ?